# Php sort array ascending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
Array ( [0] => ../files/flv/1 [1] => ../files/flv/10 [2] => ../files/flv/2 [3] => ../files/flv/3 [4] => ../files/flv/4 [5] => ../files/flv/5 [6] => ../files/flv/6 [7] => ../files/flv/7 [8] => ../files/flv/8 [9] => ../files/flv/9 )
```

I need to sort it this way:

```
Array ( [0] => ../files/flv/1 [1] => ../files/flv/2 [2] => ../files/flv/3 [3] => ../files/flv/4 [4] => ../files/flv/5 [5] => ../files/flv/6 [6] => ../files/flv/7 [7] => ../files/flv/8 [8] => ../files/flv/9 [9] => ../files/flv/10 )
```

I tried to use `sort($array,SORT_NUMERIC);`, but no luck because of this prefix `../files/flv/`

I know only this solution: `$array2 = array_map('basename', $array);` and then `sort($array2,SORT_NUMERIC);`

Is there any other solutions not so complex?

Comment: SORT_NATURAL is not working because of two dotes at start in "../files/flv/".

Comment: I tested `SORT_NATURAL` before I added my answer. Updated it with the test code now.

Comment: Gergo Erdosi i tested it on my server and here http://writecodeonline.com/php/, but it's not working. Maybe it's because of OS in server. I use CentOS 6.

Comment: I see. That service uses PHP 5.3.3, `SORT_NATURAL` was added in PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Thank you for info. So do you think there is no other ways?

Comment: You mean a less complex one? Looks already very simple to me.

Comment: @user2337706 You can use `natsort()`, see my updated answer.

Comment: yes natsort works, but it don't change key order. It outputs: "[0] => ../files/flv/1, [2] => ../files/flv/2, [1] => ../files/flv/10"

Comment: Anyway, thank you. I choose your answer. I like the minimalistic code:)

Comment: @user2337706 You can reindex the array after calling `natsort()`: `$array = array_values($array);`

Comment: You're right, it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SORT_NATURAL` instead of `SORT_NUMERIC` (requires PHP 5.4.0 or latest):

```
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

**EDIT:** I used this code to test it:

```
$array = array(
  '../files/flv/1',
  '../files/flv/10',
  '../files/flv/2'
);

sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
print_r($array);
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ../files/flv/1
    [1] => ../files/flv/2
    [2] => ../files/flv/10
)
```

**EDIT 2:** Alternatively you can use the [`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function, it works on older versions too:

```
natsort($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If "../files/flv/" path is always same you can try using str_replace function on all elements and then do sorting using sort numeric and later add same path back to all elements.

So three steps are:

1. Use foreach loop over array and use str_replace() function on ecah element.
2. do sorting as you did using sort numeric.
3. Use foreach loop over array and put the constant path back as prefix.

To make it more perfect you can do this by creating your own function and pass path as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried without the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag?

Comment: have *you* tried it? BTW, in my experience, answers suggesting 'trying' something are usually wrong here on SO... just a thought.